# Proving a sum identity for the Bernoulli numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, generating-functions, constants

I would like to prove that
$$B_{2n}=\frac{1}{2(2n-1)(2^{2n}-1)}\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)2^{2k}\binom{2n}{2k}B_{2k}\right)$$
I've checked that it holds for n=2-20. This sum came up in a pet project I have with rational approximations, which gave me good reason to believe it; checking that it held by computing the sums was just a reassurance. Does anyone have suggestions on how to go about proving this?

Though the Bernoulli numbers and binomial coefficients seem to show up together in sum formulae fairly often, I didn't find any quite like this.

Comment: How did it "come up"?

Comment: I was trying to prove an expression for cosine. I tried differentiating it twice at first, but that didn't seem to be going anywhere. Next I tried showing that their power series agree; the formula above is the last piece I need to show that is the case.

Comment: How did you come up with the expression fro cosine?

Comment: I checked it for $n=2$ to $n=1000$; it holds. How to prove it ?

Comment: If your definition of Bernoulli numbers is related to the generating function $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$, the proof is fairly straightfoward: $\frac{z}{e^z-1}\cdot(e^z-1) = z$ exactly leads to the shown recursion.

Comment: Jack: Thank you for your response - could you elaborate on how? I'm familiar with that method being used to prove the formula with only binomial coefficients multiplying each Bernoulli number, as in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208380/how-do-we-get-the-final-formula-of-the-bernoulli-number
...but I don't see how the recursion I proposed comes about from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with the sum we find

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1) 2^{2k} {2n\choose 2k} B_{2k}
\\ = 1 - (2n-1) 2^{2n} B_{2n}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (2k-1) 2^{2k} {2n\choose 2k} B_{2k}
\\ = 1 - (2n-1) 2^{2n} B_{2n}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (k-1) 2^{k} {2n\choose k} B_{k}.$$

Here we have used the fact  that the only non-zero odd index Bernoulli
number is $B_1$  and it gets canceled by the  factor $k-1.$ Continuing
with the sum term for the moment we find

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (2n-k-1) 2^{2n-k} {2n\choose 2n-k} B_{2n-k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (2n-k-1) 2^{2n-k} {2n\choose 2n-k} 
(2n-k)! [z^{2n-k}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\\ = (2n)! [z^{2n}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (2n-k-1) 2^{2n-k} \frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

Evidently we get no contribution to the coefficient extractor from the
sum when $k\gt 2n$ so we may write

$$ 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (2n-k-1) 2^{-k} \frac{z^k}{k!}
\\ = 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\left((2n-1)\exp(z/2) - \sum_{k\ge 1} k 2^{-k} \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)
\\ = 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\left((2n-1)\exp(z/2) 
- \frac{z}{2} \sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-(k-1)} \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)
\\ = 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\left((2n-1)\exp(z/2) - \frac{z}{2} \exp(z/2)\right)
\\ = 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n-1}] \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}
\left((2n-1)\exp(z/2) - \frac{z}{2} \exp(z/2)\right).$$

Observe that

$$[z^{2n-1}] (2n-1) \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1} \exp(z/2)
= [z^{2n-1}] z 
\left( \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1} \exp(z/2)\right)'
= [z^{2n-1}] z 
\left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1} \exp(z/2)
- \frac{\exp(z)}{(\exp(z)-1)^2} \exp(z/2)\right)
= [z^{2n-1}] \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}
\left( \frac{z}{2}  \exp(z/2)
- \frac{z \exp(z)}{\exp(z)-1} \exp(z/2)\right).$$

It follows that the closed form for our sum is

$$- 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n-1}]
\frac{z \exp(z)}{(\exp(z)-1)^2} \exp(z/2)
\\ = - 2^{2n} (2n)! [z^{2n}]
\frac{z^2 \exp(3z/2)}{(\exp(z)-1)^2}.$$

This is  analytic in a neigborhood  of the origin with  the pole there
being canceled  and hence the  Cauchy Coefficient Formula  applies. We
find

$$- \frac{2^{2n} (2n)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} 
\frac{z^2 \exp(3z/2)}{(\exp(z)-1)^2}
\; dz
\\ = - \frac{2^{2n} (2n)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n-1}} 
\frac{\exp(3z/2)}{(\exp(z)-1)^2}
\; dz.$$

Residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero as well.
We have the expansion

$$\frac{1}{(\exp(z)-1)^2} =
\frac{1}{(z\pm 2\pi i k)^2}
- \frac{1}{z\pm 2\pi i k} + \cdots$$

Therefore the  residues at $\pm  2\pi i k$  with $k\ge 1$  require the
derivative

$$\left(\frac{1}{z^{2n-1}} \exp(3z/2)\right)'
= - \frac{2n-1}{z^{2n}} \exp(3z/2) 
+ \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{z^{2n-1}} \exp(3z/2).$$

Evaluate to obtain

$$ - \frac{2n-1}{(\pm 2\pi i k)^{2n}} \exp(\pm 3\pi i k)
+ \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{(\pm 2\pi i k)^{2n-1}} \exp(\pm 3\pi i k)$$

The second term cancels when we add the pair of residues and we get

$$-2 \times  (2n-1) \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2n} \pi^{2n} (-1)^n k^{2n}}.$$

We also get from the second term of the expansion of $1/(\exp(z)-1)^2$

$$-\frac{1}{(\pm 2\pi i k)^{2n-1}} \exp(\pm 3\pi i k)$$

which cancels as well when paired.

Carrying out the necessary sign flip we thus obtain:

$$2 (2n-1) \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^{2n}}
= - 2 (2n-1) \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{2n}}\right)
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^{2n}}
\\ = - 2 (2n-1) \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{2n}}\right) \zeta(2n).$$

We return to  the coefficient integral and evaluate  the zeta function
term by its standard closed form to get

$$2^{2n} (2n)! \times
2 (2n-1) \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{2n}}\right)
\frac{(-1)^{n+1} B_{2n} (2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}
\\ = - 2^{2n} 
(2n-1) \frac{1}{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{2n}}\right)
B_{2n} (2\pi)^{2n}
\\ = (2n-1) (2-2^{2n}) B_{2n}.$$

We finally  obtain for the  initial sum term  from the very  start the
closed form

$$1 - (2n-1) 2^{2n} B_{2n} + (2n-1) (2-2^{2n}) B_{2n}
= 1 + (2n-1) (2-2^{2n+1}) B_{2n}
\\ = 1 + 2 (2n-1) (1-2^{2n}) B_{2n}.$$

Our formula now reads

$$B_{2n} = \frac{1}{2(2n-1)(2^{2n}-1)}
\left(1 - 1 - 2 (2n-1) (1-2^{2n}) B_{2n}\right)$$

and we have evidently proved the claim.

**Addendum.** The simplest way of  seeing that the residues of the
main function  sum to  zero is  to use the  square $\pm  \pi(2N+1) \pm
\pi(2N+1)i$ for a contour in the evaluation that passes midway between
the poles on the imaginary axis.  It then becomes possible to apply ML
and show that the integral  vanishes in $N,$ substantiating the claim.
Number the sides $\Gamma_{0,1,2,3}$ starting with the right side.  The
length of  every one  of the  four sides is  $2\pi(2N+1).$ We  get for
$\Gamma_0$  where we  parameterize with  $t$ through  $z=\pi(2N+1)+it$
where $-\pi(2N+1)\le t\le \pi(2N+1)$

$$\left| g(z) \right|
= \frac{1}{|\pi(2N+1)+it|^{2n-1}} 
\left|\frac{\exp(3(\pi(2N+1)+it)/2)}{(\exp(\pi(2N+1)+it)-1)^2}\right|
\\ \le \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1} (2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(3\pi(2N+1)/2)}
{(\exp(\pi(2N+1))\cos t - 1)^2 + (\exp(\pi(2N+1)) \sin t)^2}
\\ =  \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(3\pi(2N+1)/2)}
{\exp(2\pi(2N+1)) - 2 \exp(\pi(2N+1)) \cos t + 1}
\\ =  \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(-\pi(2N+1)/2)}
{1 - 2 \exp(-\pi(2N+1)) \cos t + \exp(-2\pi(2N+1))}.$$

Here we have used the fact that the point on $\Gamma_0$ closest to the
origin is the intersection with the real axis to bound $|1/z^{2n-1}|$.
Now clearly  the terms in the  denominator that are not  constant both
vanish (the cosine  has $|\cos t|\le 1$)  and we get using  ML for $N$
large enough the upper bound

$$\frac{2\pi(2N+1)}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(-\pi(2N+1)/2)}{1/2}
= \frac{4\exp(-\pi(2N+1)/2)}{\pi^{2n-2}(2N+1)^{2n-2}}$$

so that the contribution from  $\Gamma_0$ vanishes in the limit.  Next
we  get  for  $\Gamma_2$  where   we  parameterize  with  $t$  through
$z=-\pi(2N+1)+it$ where $-\pi(2N+1)\le t\le \pi(2N+1)$

$$\frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(-3\pi(2N+1)/2)}
{\exp(-2\pi(2N+1)) - 2 \exp(-\pi(2N+1)) \cos t + 1}.$$

We once more get two vanishing terms in the denominator and the ML
bound

$$\frac{4\exp(-3\pi(2N+1)/2)}{\pi^{2n-2}(2N+1)^{2n-2}}$$

so this vanishes too. To conclude  we need the two horizontal segments
$\Gamma_1$  and  $\Gamma_3$   which  we  parameterize  with   $z  =  t
\pm\pi(2N+1)i$ where $-\pi(2N+1)\le t\le \pi(2N+1).$ We find

$$\left| g(z) \right|
= \frac{1}{|t\pm\pi(2N+1)i|^{2n-1}} 
\left|\frac{\exp(3(t\pm\pi(2N+1)i)/2)}{(\exp(t\pm\pi(2N+1)i)-1)^2}\right|
\\ \le \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(3t/2)}
{(\exp t \cos(\pm\pi(2N+1))-1)^2 + (\exp t \sin(\pm\pi(2N+1)))^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(3t/2)}
{\exp (2t) - 2 \exp t\cos(\pm\pi(2N+1)) + 1}
\\ = \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-1}(2N+1)^{2n-1}}
\frac{\exp(3t/2)}{(\exp t +1)^2}.$$

We see  there are no  singularities in $t$ and  that for $t$  going to
minus infinity this  is asymptotic to $\exp(3t/2)$ with  the real axis
as asymptote  from above  and with  $t$ going to  plus infinity  it is
asymptotic to $\exp(-t/2)$, with the  same asymptote, also from above.
With $t$ real we differentiate to obtain:

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\exp(3t/2) (3 - \exp t)}{(\exp t +1)^3}$$

By the sign of this derivative the function is increasing to a maximum
at $t=\log 3$  and decreasing thereafter. Putting it  all together the
value  at $t=\log  3$  which  is $\frac{1}{16}  3^{3/2}$  serves as  a
constant upper bound independent of $N.$ The ML bound becomes

$$\frac{1}{8}  3^{3/2} \frac{1}{\pi^{2n-2}(2N+1)^{2n-2}}$$

which also vanishes  in $N$ (we have used $n\ge  2$ throughout).  This
shows  that the  integral along  the square  vanishes as  $N$ goes  to
infinity and  hence the residues at  the poles inside the  circle must
indeed sum to  zero as claimed and we have  justified the construction
used above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never used coefficient extractors as a formal operator before, so I appreciate that you not only answered the question but also demonstrated a new tool. The tricks you used in lines 4-6 to make the sum something you could evaluate in a closed form were very interesting.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very interesting approach. (+1)